# Extracting version from a C# assembly as part of a Jenkins pipeline

Tags: c#, windows, jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I want to extract a build version from a C# assembly as part of a Jenkins pipeline running on a Windows server. The assembly file looks like this:

```
// [...snip...]

[assembly: AssemblyConfiguration("")]
[assembly: AssemblyCompany("")]
[assembly: AssemblyProduct("BulkUpdater")]
[assembly: AssemblyCopyright("Copyright ©  2016")]

// [...snip...]

// [assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.*")]
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("3.4.1.9")]
[assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("3.4.1.9")]
```

I'm fairly new to Jenkins, but familiar with Groovy, so I turned to the obvious Groovy tools to achieve this:

```
String captureVersionFromAssembly(String assemblyFilename) {
  String version
  File file = new File(assemblyFilename)
  file.eachLine { line ->
    // avoid commented AssemblyVersion
    if (line.contains("AssemblyVersion") && !line.startsWith('//')) {
      version = line.split('"')[1]
    }
  }
  version
}
```

which correctly returns `3.4.1.9` outside of the Jenkins pipeline.

I'm aware that the Jenkins pipeline plugin requires you to give permission for pipeline scripts to use the `File` class. I have done this by registering it in the `in-process script approval` section of `Manage Jenkins`.

In a Jenkins pipeline the `File` class can't seem to find files (even when `bat 'dir'` shows them to be there.)

```
dir('omega-elms')  {
    bat 'dir'
    bat 'dir ELMS_Desktop_Application'
    echo "Working directory: ${pwd()}"
    fileExists('ELMS_Desktop_Application')
    fileExists('ELMS_Desktop_Application\\CARS')
    fileExists('ELMS_Desktop_Application\\CARS\\BulkUpdater')
    fileExists('ELMS_Desktop_Application\\CARS\\BulkUpdater\\Properties')
}

def fileExists(String filename) {
   echo "'$filename' exists? ${new File(filename).exists()}"
}
```

gives the following log:

```
[windows] E:\Jenkins\Production\workspace\test_version_extract_buildonly\omega-elms>dir
[windows]  Volume in drive E is New Volume
[windows]  Volume Serial Number is 6695-F35A
[windows]
[windows]  Directory of E:\Jenkins\Production\workspace\test_version_extract_buildonly\omega-elms
[windows]
[windows] 29/08/2017  11:38 AM    <DIR>          .
[windows] 29/08/2017  11:38 AM    <DIR>          ..
[windows] 29/08/2017  11:38 AM    <DIR>          ELMS_Desktop_Application
[windows]                0 File(s)              0 bytes
[windows]                3 Dir(s)  105,175,678,976 bytes free
[Pipeline] [windows] bat
[windows] [omega-elms] Running batch script
[windows]
[windows] E:\Jenkins\Production\workspace\test_version_extract_buildonly\omega-elms>dir ELMS_Desktop_Application
[windows]  Volume in drive E is New Volume
[windows]  Volume Serial Number is 6695-F35A
[windows]
[windows]  Directory of E:\Jenkins\Production\workspace\test_version_extract_buildonly\omega-elms\ELMS_Desktop_Application
[windows]
[windows] 29/08/2017  11:38 AM    <DIR>          .
[windows] 29/08/2017  11:38 AM    <DIR>          ..
[windows] 29/08/2017  11:38 AM    <DIR>          AppData
[windows] 29/08/2017  11:38 AM    <DIR>          CARS
[windows] 29/08/2017  11:38 AM             1,322 README.md
[windows] 29/08/2017  11:38 AM    <DIR>          Tests
[windows]                1 File(s)          1,322 bytes
[windows]                5 Dir(s)  105,175,674,880 bytes free
[Pipeline] [windows] pwd
[Pipeline] [windows] echo
[windows] Working directory: E:\Jenkins\Production\workspace\test_version_extract_buildonly\omega-elms
[Pipeline] [windows] pwd
[Pipeline] [windows] echo
[windows] 'ELMS_Desktop_Application' exists? false
[Pipeline] [windows] echo
[windows] 'ELMS_Desktop_Application\CARS' exists? false
[Pipeline] [windows] echo
[windows] 'ELMS_Desktop_Application\CARS\BulkUpdater' exists? false
[Pipeline] [windows] echo
[windows] 'ELMS_Desktop_Application\CARS\BulkUpdater\Properties' exists? false
[Pipeline] [windows] echo
[windows] 'ELMS_Desktop_Application\CARS\BulkUpdater\Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs' exists? false
```

I have also prepended the working directory to give an absolute file path:

```
String assembly = "${pwd()}\\ELMS_Desktop_Application\\CARS\\BulkUpdater\\Properties\\AssemblyInfo.cs"
```

but that doesn't solve the problem either.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you considered using C# interactive `.csx` files along with `csi.exe` to write your scripts in C# instead and leverage the power of Roslyn to extract that info?  There's probably other ways, but it's a nice, robust, and clean way to get that info, though using regular expressions is probably feasible.  Anyway, this is what we do.

Comment: Hey Kirk, thanks for this response. It does sound the most elegant way as this is an MS Build pipeline. I'll let you know how it goes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following is ugly but works:

In `appversion.bat` in `assemblyDir`:

```
@echo off
REM extract version from assembly ignoring commented out version
FOR /F delims^=^"^ tokens^=1^,2^* %%A IN ('findstr /L /B /C:"[assembly: AssemblyVersion" "AssemblyInfo.cs"') DO (
   set "version=%%B"
)
echo %version%
```

In Jenkins pipeline:

```
String versionNumber
dir(assemblyDir) {
  bat './appversion.bat >stdout'
  versionNumber = readFile('stdout').trim()
}
// ...use versionNumber here
```

Not clear yet why the `File` methods can't find files in Jenkins pipelines. It would be interesting to understand better. For example, is this a deliberate security feature?